# video element is not working properly on website

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

i have added a video on website but its not working properly on firefox.
it gets stuck in firefox, while plays well on other browsers

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    video {
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

</style>

<div class="overlay"></div>
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" id="myVideo">
    <source src="valeo.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```

Comment: Hi could  you explain what you mean by stuck - does it play part way through then stop, or does it fail to loop or... Also, please put up a working snippet which shows the problem - ie with a video that shows the problem.

Comment: it play part way through then stop.  you can show example here - https://vexmatech.com/images1/Valeo.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A video is reported as stopping part way through on Firefox.

I tested it on various browsers (Edge, Chrome, FF on Windows 10). All gave some sort of pausing but mostly they recovered and continued for a bit, then stopped.

I also downloaded the given video and played in locally on my laptop and it was fine, no pausing. I uploaded it to Youtube and it also played OK.

The video is not huge (around 14MB) but it took a few minutes to download to my laptop (which is on a reasonably good connection).

The answer seems to be that the server being used cannot serve fast enough to play video in real time consistently.

Try uploading the video to a known video-service like Youtube and notice the difference.